# How do you convert a base64 utf-8 encoded string to a binary file from bash?

Tags: bash, base64

Is there a tool that will do this in bash?

Comment: echo -n 'input' | openssl base64

Comment: `bash` does not have a bas64 encoder/decoder built in. There are utilities like `openssl` and the aptly named `base64` utility that does this though. What do you mean by "utf-8 encoded"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

## Packages

Yes, there are several. The package [`coreutils`](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/) (installed by default in debian) carry both [base32](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/base32-invocation.html) and [base64](https://www.gnu.org/software/coreutils/manual/html_node/base64-invocation.html). They could either encode or decode:

```
$ printf '%s' "abc" | base64
YWJj

$ printf '%s' "abc" | base64 | base64 -d
abc
```

Understand that using echo might add a trailing new line that will change the resulting base64 encoded string:

```
$ echo "abc" | base64
YWJjCg==
```

There are also other packages that have similar tools in packages `basez` and `openssl`. The latter is also usually installed by default, the former is not.

```
$ printf '%s' "abc" | openssl base64
YWJj
```

## Encoding

That the source string is encoded in any locale (codepage) is irrelevant to base64 encoding. A base64 program encodes bytes, not characters.

```
$ printf '%s' "éäìǫ" | base64 | base64 -d
éäìǫ
```

Will work on any system exactly the same. Well, in any sane system in which `echo "éäìǫ"` will also print `éäìǫ` on the command line.

Of course, if the source string is encoded in one system and then decoded in a system with a different locale, it is quite probable that you will get a [Mojibake](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mojibake) string. That is not a problem to be solved by base64, it is an issue to be solved by changing the encoding of the string. Probably with [`iconv`](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/iconv.1.html).

```
$ echo -n "Москва" | base64            # in a utf8 locale
0JzQvtGB0LrQstCw
```

However, in a Cyrillic locale with iso889-5 (maybe ru_RU.ISO-8859-5, there are other languages with Cyrillic):

```
$ echo "0JzQvtGB0LrQstCw" | base64 -d
ааОбаКаВаА

$ echo "0JzQvtGB0LrQstCw" | base64 -d | iconv -f utf8 -t iso8859-5
Москва
```

Comment: why `printf '%s'` instead of `echo -n`?

Comment: @qwr `echo -n` is not portable. POSIX states the behaviour of `-n` is: "... implementation-defined". `printf '%s'` on the other hand has POSIX specified behaviour.