# Difference between wc -c and ${#}?

Tags: bash, shell-script, special-characters, wc, base64

I've created script, where I encoded string 28 times with base64. Then I wanted to echo count of chars in outputted string.

First I used `${#var}` which gave me 34070.

Then I tried on the same string

```
script.sh | wc -c
```

which gave me 34071.

```
#!/bin/bash
var="9M"
for i in {1..28};do
var=$(echo $var | base64)
done
echo ${#var}
```

What exactly does make those two outputs different?

Comment: Welcome, try with `echo -n "${var}"`...

Comment: See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/464023/117549 and https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/454190/117549

Answer (score 5):

As you can see in this example using the command `od` showing the bytes, it prints the newline:

```
$ echo foo | od -c -b
0000000   f   o   o  \n
        146 157 157 012
0000004
```

So in this case, `wc -c` as well as `wc -m` is counting the newline.

Without the newline:

```
$ echo -n foo | od -c -b
0000000   f   o   o
        146 157 157
0000003
```

So if you use `echo`, add the `-n` option so it doesn't print the newline, or `printf`:

```
$ printf "%s" foo | od -c -b
0000000   f   o   o
        146 157 157
0000003
```

Answer (score 3):

The extra character is the newline. You can see it if you do, for example:

```
echo $var | hd | tail
```

Comment: I don't know what `hd` is (it's not in any package of my distro, at least), but `od` is part of POSIX and available in GNU's coreutils.

Comment: @JoL you can do then `echo $var | od -Ax -t x1z | tail` and get an output similar to that of `hd`.